# How pass query result from view to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in which I select parameters and execute processing.
On the next page I view the results and I have to give the possibility both to export these results and to save them.
Now I was thinking of storing the processing results in a temporary table and then proceed with two actions: do you think is correct as an approach?

In the case how should I proceed:

- create a physical copy of the table to be used as a support? (it seems unprofessional as an option);
- create "temporary" a temporary table (#tmptable) as a copy of the original? (Could I have problems managing it from one query execution to the other due to its "temporary" scope?)
- enter data in a datatable and save it in session (I do not know if too heavy as a choice)
- other?

I am grateful for the information you can provide me.
Greetings.

Comment: "export and save" could be done from the CLient (JavaScript). If you want help with a server side solution then provide much more info about size, structure, lifecycle etc.

Comment: yes, I do so with jquery but I do not want to repeat the processing in the actions "export" and "save". How can I do to pass the data displayed in the view (in webgrid)? I first have to store them in some way?

Comment: If you are adamant that you don't want to do any reprocessing then why not store the results as JSON in the front end? There should be a library out there to export JSON as a spreadsheet etc